# Create input parameter box

Tags: matlab

I create a display box in MATLAB and enter input values which are read by matlab code

```
prompt={'size1'};
name = 'Input';
defaultans = {'30'};
options.Interpreter = 'size1';
answer = inputdlg(prompt,name,[1 40],defaultans,options);
```

However, I want to enter values of size1 in the form of matrix like 
size1 = [2,4,7,10]

All the values entered in input box,should be identified in the next part of prewritten code which is as follows

```
t(:,1) = size1;
```

It would be helpful if anyone can let me know how can i modify my code accordingly.

Comment: This `{2,4,7,10}|` is not a matrix? What do you want the user to input? Will it always be just 4 elements for a vector?

Comment: Yes.... [2,4,7,10] is just an example to explain what i was trying to say incase I am not clear with explanation. 

No, its not about just 4 elements. It can be any number of elements like 6 or 7 or any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `str2num` function to evaluate a sting (the input) as a matrix. So get the matrix using

```
defaultans = {'[2,4,7,10]'};
answer = inputdlg('size1:','Input',1,defaultans);
% Click okay, answer='[2,4,7,10]'

matrixFromAnswer = str2num(answer{1});
% matrixFromAnswer = [2,4,7,8];

% Could check here if it is the right size etc. 
% For instance str2num will return [] if the input was invalid.

t(:,1) = size1(:); 
% The (:) ensures it is a column vector as you are assigning it to a column of t...
```

---

Alternatively, do something like this

```
answer = inputdlg('Enter your vector with a new line for each element:','Input',5);

% Input: 
%          3
%          2
%          1

matrixFromAnswer = str2num(answer{1});
% matrixFromAnswer = [3;2;1]
```

---

This is actually shown in *Example 2* of Matlab's [`inputdlg` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html#bqvo453)

Comment: Thank you very much